# Current image scroller replacement with JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, html, image, scroll

I am currently using javascript to implement a javascript scroller on my webpage. However, this is not compatible with any DOCTYPEs and instead displays a stationary picture. I was wondering if any one had any idea how I would implement this using jQuery, Mootools or any other such library.
The sites are detailed below with and without a DOCTYPE. 
With DOCTYPE: [web.me.com/zubby](http://web.me.com/zubby)  
Without DOCTYPE: [web.me.com/zubby/2.html](http://web.me.com/zubby/2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's been answered guys: [Javascript image scroller not working with DOCTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106479/javascript-image-scroller-not-working-with-doctype)